# Calculate the difference in time grouped by id

Tags: r

Using this code :

```
idCol <- c('1','1','1','2','2','3','3')
rowNumIdCol <- c('1','2','3','4','5','6','7')
stepCol <- c('step1')
step1Col <- c('30-12-2010:11.02', '31-12-2010:10.06', '05-01-2011:15.12','01-03-2017:09.00', '01-05-2017:09.00', '01-06-2017:09.00', '01-07-2017:09.00')
mydata <- data.frame(idCol , rowNumIdCol , step1Col)
colnames(mydata) <- c('id' , 'rowNumId' , 'step1')
```

creates dataframe :

[image]

I'm attempting to calculate the differences between each timestamp grouped by id.

Here is code I'm trying :

```
mydata$"Days spent" <- unlist(by(mydata, mydata$id, function(x) as.numeric(difftime(ymd_hms(x$step1),ymd_hms(x$step1)[1], units= "days"))))
```

But this returns an incorrect dataframe 'Days spent' column :

[image]

364.9994 & -9464.9554 are incorrect values.

I'm not calculating the time differences correctly ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the `formt` of 'step1', we need to use `dmy_hm` to convert it to 'datetime' class

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
mydata %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    mutate(DaysSpent = as.numeric(difftime(dmy_hm(step1), 
                         dmy_hm(step1)[1], units = 'days')))
```

Comment: Actually, you'd need `dmy_hm`. Using `dmy_hms` e.g. `30-12-2010:11.02` would be parsed as `2020-12-30 10:11:02`